# Is there a way to display data to textbox after search? Codeigniter Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to fetch and display the id in textbox after the data is correctly fetched from the textbox.

I need to view the other table fields data from the textbox

Here is my View and Ajax

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Class Code:</h5>
            <small><li>Only teachers shall give you code</li></small><br>
            <input type="text" id="code" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Enter class code to join" name="code" required />
            <span id="code_result"></span>  
            <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control col-md-2" />
    </div>
```

Ajax - So I need to fetch the id but for my code, it does not display

```
//Verify
$('#code').on("change keyup paste", function(){
    var code = $('#code').val();  
       if(code != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>students/check_code_avalibility",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{code:code},  
                 success:function(data){  
                      $('#code_result').html(data);  
                      $('input[name=id]').val(data.id); // I need to fetch this data
                 }  
            });  
       }    
});
```

Controller - Here I verify if the data is correct

```
function check_code_avalibility()  
{  

          if(!$this->student_model->is_code_available($_POST["code"]))  
          {  
               echo '<label class="text-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Invalid Code</label>';  
          }  
          else  
          {  
               echo '<label class="text-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Code Available </label><hr>';  
               echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Join to Class</button>'; 
          }  

}
```

Model

```
function is_code_available($code)  
{  
     $this->db->where('code', $code);  
     $query = $this->db->get("groups");  
     if($query->num_rows() > 0)  
     {  
          return true;  
     }  
     else  
     {  
          return false;  
     }  
}
```

Comment: You seem to be copy pasting solutions but not trying to understand. Your `data` is a string, how could it have an `id` value?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I've modified this and understood it clearly. Can you please provide an output? thank you.

Comment: What value are you expecting from `data.id`?

Comment: So in your code, where is the query that retrieves id from the model?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava what do you mean by query? it's this  `$this->db->where('code', $code);  
     $query = $this->db->get("groups");`

Comment: If you want `check_code_avalibility()` to return an id, then you can't `echo` from it. You need to return a JSON object that will have the html as one property and the id as another.

Comment: @El_Vanja - how  can I modify my code? kindly produce an output please sir? thanks

Comment: @El_Vanja - it would be highly appreciated to learn, thank you again.

Comment: How do you get `id` from `student_model`? Is it a public property or does it have a getter method?

Comment: @El_Vanja it's just a public property sir. Why?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you must modify your `check_code_avalibility` function to return data instead of echoing html. When you do something like this in javascript:

```
.val(data.id)
```

that means you're expecting an object that has an `id` property. But your PHP function isn't returning an object. It's returning a string (your html output). There is no `id`, so you can't use it.

If you want to return an object for javascript, the best way is to use JSON. See a [`json_encode` example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-examples). So, instead of echoing html in your function, you should store that html in an array under some key:

```
$output['html'] = '<label class="... and so on';
```

Note that if you're echoing multiple lines, you would need to concatenate them before adding to the array. Inside your javascript, this html output would now be available under `data.html` (because that how I've named the array key).

Additionally, you'd need to add the ID you want to that same array:

```
$output['id'] = $this->student_model->id;
```

If you return a JSON encoded version of this array, you'll have both the html and the ID available to you in javascript.

Comment: it's kinda confusing for me

Comment: can you refer to my code as well? I cannot understand this very well. Should I change my controller or what?

Comment: this does not answer my question.